# No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, server

Please help me! The first time when I setup PostgreSql and Rails on Linux, I only need run `sudo service postgresql restart`. It works. Recently I have installed hadoop and made some change on file permission. And then, when I cd to Rails project and run `rails s`, above errors messages occurs. I don't know why. I spent two days trying so many avaiable solutions on internet. It is still not working.

Comment: What a result of `sudo service postgresql status`?

Comment: `postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since T3 2016-05-03 14:04:35 ICT; 1h 32min ago
  Process: 2383 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2383 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Th05 03 14:04:35 quyen-HP-1000-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RD...
Th05 03 14:04:35 quyen-HP-1000-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
`

Comment: This is result @kunashir

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you don't have permissions to create the file in /var/run/postgresql from the "postgres" owner OS user. Sudo won't make a difference as the service script itself initiates as the postgres owner/user.

Check permissions on /var/run/postgresql.

Try starting it manually (not using the servcie script) with

```
pg_ctl start -d $PGDATA
```

Check PostgreSQL log files (default: /var/log/pgsql) for the output to see the true reason it's not starting.

My bet is the permissions.

Comment: I don't know why `pg_ctl` is command not found in my case @d1ll1nger

Comment: It's probably not in your path. Which version of PostgreSQL are you using? It will usually be installed in /var/lib/pgsql-9.5/bin if you're using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: I tried it and there errors `2016-05-03 13:30:27 ICT [1662-2] DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root.
2016-05-03 14:03:23 ICT [2315-1] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" has group or world access
2016-05-03 14:03:23 ICT [2315-2] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
2016-05-03 14:04:35 ICT [2381-1] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" has group or world access`

Comment: There's your answer. Your data directory of /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main has too many permissions for groups or world access whom shouldn't be interfering with your PostgreSQL database. 

chown -R postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
chmod -R 700 /var/lib/postgresql/main

Comment: Can you remote debug this error for me, please? I am really exhausted when I can't make improvement.

Comment: Have you run the two commands mentioned above? The chmod and the chown command?

Are you still getting the same error as above?

Comment: Yes..I run all command. And command to run server: `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_ctl start -D /etc/postgresql/9.5/main`. New errors:  `LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.auto.conf"
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
`

Comment: When you are free, Can you use teamviewer to see problem for me?. It will be appreciated.

Comment: What permissions are on /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main?

`ls -lrt /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`

Comment: It like this:   `drwxrwxrwx 5 postgres postgres 4096 Th05  4 02:12 base`. But I found that I used `chmod 777 -R /etc` before. So I wonder if it is reason why my postgresql not working?